# AdminLTE submenu expands then collapses

Tags: javascript, jquery, submenu, adminlte

I'm using AdminLTE in a project that was started by someone else

The behavior I see when I add a submenu is that it expands and then collapses immediately

I've tried using the complete `<aside class="main-sidebar">...</aside>` from the index.html page, and still I get the same behavior as seen here -https://gyazo.com/e88b049ccd7b2d06d65ccc7986166cdf

If I open the index.html from the template locally it works perfectly fine

I think this project might be missing something, but can't figure out what... Tried loading all js and I see no errors in the console

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you got the answer, I am getting same issue???

Comment: not really, I had to use something else

Answer (score 0):

The sidebar behavior is not controlled by the index.html file but by the app.js file located in the /dist/js folder of adminlte.
You must have this file (among others) in your project.

What I suggest is first to look if your app.js file has not been modified by the previous guy who worked on hte project or if you could have elsewhere some scripts that overwrite the default sidebar behavior.

The original code that controls the left sidebar begins from line 380 of the app.js file (adminlte v2.3.6) and is as follow :

```
$.AdminLTE.tree = function(menu) {
  var _this = this;
  var animationSpeed = $.AdminLTE.options.animationSpeed;
  $(document).off('click', menu + ' li a')
      .on('click', menu + ' li a', function(e) {
          //Get the clicked link and the next element
          var $this = $(this);
          var checkElement = $this.next();

          //Check if the next element is a menu and is visible
          if ((checkElement.is('.treeview-menu')) && (checkElement.is(':visible')) && (!$('body').hasClass('sidebar-collapse'))) {
              //Close the menu
              checkElement.slideUp(animationSpeed, function() {
                  checkElement.removeClass('menu-open');
                  //Fix the layout in case the sidebar stretches over the height of the window
                  //_this.layout.fix();
              });
              checkElement.parent("li").removeClass("active");
          }
          //If the menu is not visible
          else if ((checkElement.is('.treeview-menu')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
              //Get the parent menu
              var parent = $this.parents('ul').first();
              //Close all open menus within the parent
              var ul = parent.find('ul:visible').slideUp(animationSpeed);
              //Remove the menu-open class from the parent
              ul.removeClass('menu-open');
              //Get the parent li
              var parent_li = $this.parent("li");

              //Open the target menu and add the menu-open class
              checkElement.slideDown(animationSpeed, function() {
                  //Add the class active to the parent li
                  checkElement.addClass('menu-open');
                  parent.find('li.active').removeClass('active');
                  parent_li.addClass('active');
                  //Fix the layout in case the sidebar stretches over the height of the window
                  _this.layout.fix();
              });
          }
          //if this isn't a link, prevent the page from being redirected
          if (checkElement.is('.treeview-menu')) {
              e.preventDefault();
          }
      });};
```

Comment: Sorry dude this didn't work for me I add this code as a .js file and I added the file path to the angular.json file too but didn't give any result.